# Flutter Qs : The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

So I already make Condition where if the data called is null so it will Show No Data but it still have an Error.

Here's the code

```
Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (data[index] == null) {
                    return Container(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                "No News"
                            )
                        )
                    );
                  } else {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                DetailNewsScreen(
                                  data: data[index],
                                )));
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        child: Row(
```

but it still show error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check if your `data` variable is `null`, otherwise you cannot call `data.length` as the `itemCount`

You're currently checking if `data[index]` is not null but not `data` itself

You could try :

```dart
Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (data[index] == null) {
                    return Container(child: Center(child: Text("No News")));
                  } else {
                    // return whatever widget you want
                  } 
                }),
          ),
```

Comment: it work but why the text didnt seem to appears

Comment: if you're talking about the "No News" text,  it won't show if data is null, because data[index] then doesn't exist

Comment: aa I see, can I show it when the data is null?

Answer (score 1):

the `data` is null, not `data[someIndex]`

```
itemCount: data.length,
```

You didnt cover the case where `data==null`. The most straightforward way of fixing it, is to assing empty array.

`if(data==null) data=[];` somewhere prior building the view.

Comment: can you show me how to fix it using my code?